# 100% Accuracy on test dataset using a previous developed model oputput

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, xgboost, machine-learning-model

My dependent variable is a probability that is sourced from someone else's classification model. I am using this probability as a dependent variable as I don't have the actual data. On building an xgboost algorithm, the accuracy is 100%. There is no data leakage - but I wanted to ask - is a 100% accuracy possible when modeling a previously developed algorithm?

Comment: How do you know there's no data leakage in the other classification model? If I give you a feature vector that perfectly predicts the target class, it's quite possible that I cheated in the first place by simply copying the target class and giving it to you as a feature vector.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the community. If I understood correctly:

1. you have a dataset whose target labels (aka ground truth) you don't know, so you figured these out by assigning the output of another model from someone else --> I guess **this pre-trained model was built with the same dataset right**?
2. you built a new model on this dataset, using as target values the other model's output as your ground truth, giving you a 100% accuracy --> you convert the predicted probability to the corresponding label is it?

This might mean:

- your model is providing the same output labels as the other model trained on the same dataset; this is not strange, **mainly if the models are of the same type** (e.g. tree-based models as your xgboost), mainly assuming the pretrained model outputs fit the real target values
- the **data** is quite **easy to "learn"**, so both models provide similar results over the same target labeling
- to take into account: **accuracy might not be an optimal metric**, taking a look at how much unbalanced the dataset is (it is, what is the ratio between the different classes).

Nevertheless, I would make sure to find the real and precise corresponding targets to go on with confidence on your problem.